# Calculating percentage of small grids in coarse grid (fill ratio)

Tags: raster, zonal-statistics, grass-gis

I am doing an analysis of two rasters in grassgis.
I am trying to determine the number of small grids (resolution=800×800) that are included (overlapped?) in the coarse grid (resolution=249×229) when the two rasters are superimposed. I would like to determine the number of small grids (resolution = 800 x 800) and the percentage of the coarse grid that is occupied by the small grids (filling rate) when the two rasters are superimposed.

To give an example, suppose that it is possible to lay out a maximum of 10 small grids in a coarse grid, and that there are 6 small grids overlapping in a particular coarse grid. I want to compute a coarse raster such that each grid has a value of 60% (or 0.6 as a percentage). (Assuming a resolution of 249 x 229)

How do I calculate the percentage from the number of small grids?

I didn't understand the concept of "grid" myself, so I summarized it with a drawing.

[image]

Comment: You should pose only one question each time.
I would use the "Raster pixels to Polygons" tool with Qgis. Then you would have two polygon layers. You can use the polygon layer corresponding to a small grid by location as input and select by location its features that overlap/are within the polygon layer corresponding to the coarse grid.  What do you mean by resolution in this case? It looks weird to me the fact that the Small grid has a higher resolution (8oo x 800 units (pixels? meters?)) than the coarse grid. Also, the coarse grid has a weird resolution of 249 x 229 units (pixels? meters?).

Comment: I'm also confused by your use of the terms "small grid" and "coarse grid". Usually when I say "coarse" I mean that the cell size is ** larger*. So in your example, the 800x800 grid would be the coarse grid, and the 229x249 would be the fine grid.

Comment: Further, I don't get the 60% that you put in your question. Could you possibly add a figure to show what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It was very helpful.
I added figures!!
After overlapping two rasters, I want to generate a raster with a resolution of 249x229 and a fill factor per grid as a value.

Comment: So I see that some of the grid cells have values, and the others are empty? (Are the empty cells "NA" - i.e. no value??). And you want to calculate for each coarse grid cell, the precent of cells in the fine resolution with some value (not NA). Is that it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can calculate the percent of high resolution cells with some value contained within each low resolution cell. For this example I took an elevation DEM at 1 arcsecond resolution (about 30 m) from the ASTER DEM project. Then I set all values below 750 meters to NULL in order to have lots of cells with null values. Next I changed the computational region to 5 arcseconds, so there were 25 high res cells (5X5) in each low res cell. I then used the GRASS GIS `r.resamp.stats` module ( [Manual page here](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/r.resamp.stats.html) ) to calulate the count of (non-null) cells in each low res cell, and finally divided by 25 (the number of high res cells in each low res cell) to get percent.

Here's the code:

```
# Using an ASTER DEM tile
r.external ~/GIS/DEM/ASTER_DEM/ISR/ASTGTM_N30E034_dem.tif output=dem --o
# Set computational region to a small mountain area of that tile
g.region rast=dem w=34.5 e=34.8 s=30.4 n=30.7 -ap
# Now prepare a clipped DEM but with all low elevations set to null()
r.mapcalc "dem_clip = if(dem >= 750, dem, null())" --o

# Reset computational region to low resolution
g.region res=0:00:05
# Call r.resamp.stats with the "count" method
r.resamp.stats input=dem_clip output=dem_lowres method=count
# Divide by 25 (number of high res cells in each low res cell) to get percent
r.mapcalc "dem_percent = dem_lowres / 25.0"
```

Here are plots of the high resolution DEM and the low res percent of cells.

[image: Higres DEM]

[image: Lowres count]

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I was able to express it well in the way you suggested.
Thank you.